Reference appear twice inside the article document of synopsis
MWE:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}%line strech
\setstretch{1.40}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% page numbering %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\chead{}
\cfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\lfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}% <- added
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
Title Page information
        \end{center}        
    \end{titlepage}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \section{First} 
    \newpage
    \section{Second} 
    \newpage
    \section{Third} 
    \newpage
    \section{Fourth} 
    \newpage
    \section{Fifth}
    \newpage
    \section{Sixth} 
    \newpage
    \section{Seventh} 
    \newpage
    \section{References}
    %\newpage
    \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
    \bibliography{my.bib}   
\end{document}

In my latex document, when I compile it produces reference title twice (one as section of document and other might be bibliography command). How can I fix the problem? Please help me.

Delete \section{References}

You are right but in the table of content section will not reflect.

Use \addcontentsline

I don't have any idea about it.

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}     \bibliography{my.bib}

@Stephen that might not be a good idea (can end up pointing to the wrong page if you do it like that

but the section number (for Reference) don't appear in the document.

Use the tocbibind package to automatically get bib etc into the TOC

Since you're using unsrtnat as bibliography style, you should load also natbib and in this case it's simple to have a numbered reference section.
Here's your test document with some fixes:

I reorganized the package loading section;
the settings for fancyhdr have been simplified;
using a different page numbering style for the title page avoids problems with hyperlinks;
instead of \thepage \hspace{1pt} I used \thepage{}

If you don't want a useless hyperlink in every footer, do
\fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage{} of \pageref*{LastPage}}

Complete example
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% unneeded
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}%line strech
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setstretch{1.40}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% page numbering %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}% <- added
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% get numbered reference section
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{\refname}}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Alph}% so hyperref doesn't complain
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
Title Page information
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{First}

\nocite{*}
\newpage

\section{Second} 
\newpage

\section{Third} 
\newpage

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{sandym.bib}   

\end{document}



Thank you so much sir. Thanks for correcting me. Hoping for same help in future also.
